# Apex Query to TaskWhoRelation

Tags: apex, trigger, shared-activities, taskrelation

Here is my code. Need help to find the right way to check IF logic with TaskWhoRelation.relationId instead objTask.WhoId. Any type of help will be grateful.

```
set<Id> setIds=new set<Id>();
Set<Id> taskIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();
for ( Task t : [SELECT Id, Subject, (SELECT RelationId, Type FROM TaskWhoRelations) FROM Task WHERE Id IN :taskIds]){
    for(TaskWhoRelation tskWhoRelated :t.TaskWhoRelations){
         System.debug('Print Task Contacts: ' + tskWhoRelated); 
        if (tskWhoRelated.RelationId != null ){  // checking if size is greater than 0 
            setIds.add(tskWhoRelated.RelationId); // then add in contactId list

        }  
    }
}
map<Id,Contact> mapContact=new map<Id,Contact>([select id,Last_Relationship_Call__c from contact where id in :setIds]);
map<Id,Lead> mapLead=new map<Id,Lead>([select id,Last_Relationship_Call__c from Lead where id in :setIds]);
system.debug('****lstObjectFieldMappingInfo***'+lstObjectFieldMappingInfo);
for(Task objTask : trigger.new){
    if(objTask.WhoId != null){
        integer counter=0;
        boolean isSubjectEmail=false;
        if(objTask.subject != null && objTask.subject.startsWithIgnoreCase('email')){
            counter++;
            isSubjectEmail=true;                
        }
    if( counter == lstObjectFieldMappingInfo.size() || counter > 0){
        Sobject objSobject=objTask.WhoId.getSObjectType().newSObject();
        objSobject.put('Id',objTask.WhoId);
        if(mapContact.containsKey(objTask.WhoId)){
            if(objTask.subject == 'Note'){
             objSobject.put('Last_Note_Date__c',objTask.ActivityDate);
             else if( !(isSubjectEmail) && mapContact.get(objTask.WhoId).Last_Relationship_Call__c == null || (mapContact.get(objTask.WhoId).Last_Relationship_Call__c != null && mapContact.get(objTask.WhoId).Last_Relationship_Call__c < objTask.ActivityDate)){
                        objSobject.put('Last_Relationship_Call__c',objTask.ActivityDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this post [How to Update Leads or Contacts When Shared Activities Logged](https://douglascayers.com/2016/12/26/how-to-update-leads-or-contacts-when-shared-activities-logged/), which gives you a better approach to understand activities logs.

Updated post [How to Update Lead or Contact When Activity Logged](https://douglascayers.com/2017/04/02/use-process-builder-to-update-related-records-when-activities-logged/)

In case you just want to use code:
Note: seems there is an issue from (2016) for quering TaskWhoRelation records which only return Primary Contact.

> Set taskIds = trigger.newMap.keySet();
>
> Set contactIds = new Set ();
>
> List tasks = [SELECT Id, Subject, (SELECT RelationId, Type from > TaskWhoRelations where Type = 'Contact') FROM Task WHERE Id IN :taskIds];
>
> for (Task t :tasks)
>
> ```
> for (TaskWhoRelation tWho :t.TaskWhoRelations)
>
>   contactIds.add(tWho.RelationId);
> ```

Comment: I have all logic in code hence have to use that option. But it seems like it is still not updating all contact. Only primary contact got updated with ActivityDate. Does this code solution ever been worked for anyone?

Comment: If my dode example don't let you update all contacts, you may want to try this other option:  [SELECT Id, Subject, (SELECT RelationId from TaskRelations WHERE isWhat = false) FROM Task WHERE Id IN :taskIds]; then loop through the all TaskRelations  and validate if RelationId startd with 003 (Contact) id. this query may bring all contact relations.

Comment: Actually, I think other codes in logic not allowing to read that value.. I just updated the original post. If you can be any more help here. Thank you for your time and all your support.@sam.a